# Orchard ShellSettingsManager always returns the second Tenant settings

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I'm running a multi tenant Orchard Web app . 
When running the first time (with multi tenant already set up) when requesting `~/` I'm calling a service to get the current Shell settings.

and its returning me the second Tenant `ShellSettings` with BaseUrl (`~/Tenant1`)  :

`_ShellManager.LoadSettings().FirstOrDefault()`

is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to access the shell settings for the current tenant is by injecting shell settings  into your constructor like so:

```
private readonly ShellSettings _shellSettings;

public MyClass(ShellSettings shellSettings) {
  _shellSettings = _shellSettings;
}
```